# org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have web service URL:

```
http://myservice.local/aprovalanduser/?format=json&Name=India
```

When I am calling this URL using

```java
resttemplate httpsrestTemplate.getForObject(uri, userdetails[].class)
```

I am getting error:

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized

in the web service method:

```
method: "GET", 
data: xmlData, 
contentType: "application/xml", 
dataType: "xml", 
async: true, 
crossDomain: false,
```

I am setting the header only for XML like below:

```java
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code which does basic authentication as suggested by @ekem chitsiga

```
String plainCreds = "username:password";
byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String url = "http://myservice.local/aprovalanduser/?format=json&Name=India";
ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, Object.class);
response.getBody();
```

Answer (score 2):

Http status code 401 means that you need to supply credentials to access the service. The way you present the credentials dependends on the authentication mechanism used by the service

For example if it uses Basic Authentication then you need to add a Authorization request header with Basic prefix and a base64 encoded combination of username and password separated by :

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. A link to page/docs with an example of how to do this would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
String plainCreds_usuario = Constants.CREDENCIAL_REST_API_ODATA_USUARIO;
        String plainCreds_password = Constants.CREDENCIAL_REST_API_ODATA_PASSWORD;
        
        String plainCreds = plainCreds_usuario+":"+plainCreds_password;
        
        byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
        byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
        String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(Constants.getRutaApiOdataHttp() + Constants.WS_REST_API_ODATA_GET_EMPRESAS, HttpMethod.GET, request, Object.class);
        response.getBody();
        
        if(response != null && response.getBody() != null){             
            System.out.println("YES");
            System.out.println(response.getBody().toString());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("NONES");
        }
```